# MySQL DROP all tables foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

I need to alter my table that is modify table data type from `bigint` to `int` , totally there are 200 tables in database but because of foreign key constraints i am not able to alter my table.

I tried `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` but it doesn't work for modifying the data type.

Please tell me is there any other way to modify the table without affecting the existing table.

Comment: ..... 1. what command did you type. 2. what happend. 3. what does "doesn't work" mean. 4. if you got any errors, show them here. 5. Did you change all rows to int (because otherwise the foreign key cant be kept in place)

Comment: +1 for asking such question. Not sure why people gave you -2

Comment: +1 Because it is a good question. And there is an answer - to recreate foreign keys (see Augusto's answer). So, all tables must be refactored manually, ...or (maybe) somehow to generate refactoring SQL script.

Answer (score 1):

This not as simple as you think. As, I assume, that the comlumn you want to change is part of the primary key of the table.

So these are the steps you need to follow in MySQL

- drop all FKs to the table
- update the datatype on the table
- update the datatype *on all the tables* that have a FK to the table you want to change.
- recreate all the FKs

Apart from what I mentioned above, there's no other way to "cheat" mysql to change a column that is part of a PK/FK.

MySQL needs the columns in a PK and FK to be exactly the same datatype, otherwise you won't be able to recreate the FKs.